# Indexing for Sphinx of legacy data generating some errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

A rails 3.2.18 application is being created, migrating data from a rails 2.3.10 application.  Data is being ported over via pg_dump and loaded via psql command, without any errors.

One model of the 13 that are indexed via thinking_sphinx is getting some errors.  Only 1 in 8.5 docs is being indexed overall.

```
indexing index 'norm_core'...
ERROR: index 'norm_core': sql_range_query: ERROR:  integer out of range
 (DSN=pgsql://jerdvo:***@localhost:5432/fna_development).
total 1019 docs, 234688 bytes
```

The index file is

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :norm, :with => :active_record do
    indexes data
    indexes titolo
    indexes massima
    indexes numero
    indexes norm_fulltext
    indexes region.name, :as => :region
    indexes normtype.name, :as => :normtype

    has region_id
    has normtype_id
    has data, :as => :data_timestamp
end
```

I'm unsure about the syntax of the last element with `data_timestamp`, as it could be legacy syntax... It applies to a date field - from schema:

```
    t.date     "data"
```

Other models have the same indexing scenario on a date. But none have generated the error.
[assuming that line has to change, should one first doe `rake ts:configure` before index or rebuild?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two tips for debugging this:

- Comment out all of the attributes (the `has` calls), run the `ts:index` task, confirm it works. Then introduce each attribute back in one at a time, see which one is causing the error.
- Check the maximum values of any attribute columns that don't work (e.g. `SELECT MAX(data) FROM norms`), see if that data is valid and also within the range of a 32-bit unsigned integer.

If it's one of the foreign keys that's ventured into 64-bit int territory, then you can specify that as the data type:

```
has normtype_id, :type => :bigint
```

If it's the date column, then you'll need to inform Thinking Sphinx to translate date/time values to be 64-bit integer timestamps by adding the following to each necessary environment in `config/thinking_sphinx.yml`:

```
development:
  64bit_timestamps: true
```

A third source of the issue, I guess, is the primary key being bigger than a 32-bit integer, but TS should detect bigint columns and handle document ids appropriately. Of course, Sphinx also needs to be compiled to handle 64-bit document ids, but I would expect this to be the default (the compile flag, for reference's sake, is `--enable-id64`).

And if none of that helps... then, well, I'm at a loss to what the cause may be.

Comment: Hit it on its head!  it was the date column.  I suppose `64bit_timestamps: true` should go to production too one day.  Looking at the thinking_sphinx config file has this line (which may be the real source of the problem) `use_64_bit: true` seems to be middling in its purpose... is this rails2 legacy? keep? remove?

Comment: Yeah, that's for TS v1/v2 - this new setting is its equivalent.